# How to redirect http to https in angular 5

Tags: node.js, https, angular5

I am using angular 5 and have code setup on AWS server. I have also installed SSL on my server.

I need to redirect requests to https if they are coming from http. Please suggest where and what code I need to do for this.

Comment: This would typically be done in the webserver config, not Angular.

Comment: @ceejayoz You mean in node server.js file or something in AWS server ?

Comment: I mean in the AWS server, most likely in your Apache or nginx (depending which webserver you chose) config.

Comment: @ceejayoz I am using node npm server. Could you please suggest any link where I can have some idea to do it with node npm server